Missing adforn.sty in MiKTeX Installation - Manual Download Lacks .sty File
Update: This should now be fixed in MiKTeX according to https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/444#issuecomment-2543871156. Apologies for adding this into the question. I would normally post this as an answer, but the question has been closed. If somebody with MiKTeX could confirm this, that would be great. --- cfr

I'm trying to compile a LaTeX document that requires the adforn package for decorative symbols. However, I encountered the error:
! LaTeX Error: File `adforn.sty` not found.

Steps I’ve Taken So Far:

MiKTeX Console: I tried installing adforn directly via the MiKTeX Console. The package appears in the C:\Users\Gaming\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex\latex\adforn folder, but no .sty file is inside, only metadata files under tpm\packages.

Manual Download: I downloaded adforn manually from CTAN. Inside the ZIP file, I found a folder named adforn, but upon searching, no adforn.sty file was present—only font files and documentation.

LaTeX Compilation: MiKTeX is set to automatically install missing packages, but it still throws the missing file error, and refreshing the FNDB didn’t resolve it.


My Questions:

Is adforn.sty supposed to be part of the package, or does adforn rely exclusively on font files without a .sty file?

If there’s no adforn.sty, how can I use the adforn package for ornaments, or should I switch to a different package like pgfornament or pifont?


I would appreciate guidance on whether adforn.sty should exist, and if not, how to configure MiKTeX to properly recognize the package.

Indeed, it seems, that the MiKTeX adforn package only contains the font files, map files and metrics but not adforn.sty, adforn.enc and uornementsadf.fd. You should report this. To generate the files (as hotfix only!), download adforn.ins and adforn.dtx and run tex adforn.ins (or maybe latex adforn.ins).

CTAN don't hold generated files except for documentation. adforn was updated to use dtx/ins and docstrip, so there is no adforn.sty on CTAN now. it has to be generated as @cabohah explained. if miktex doesn't do this, that's a bug on miktex's side.

use pdflatex adforn.ins. at least, that's what I used when testing. (although I can't see why I used pdflatex. looking at the file, pdftex should work, I think.)

@cabohah https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/444 but it would be good if somebody familiar with miktex could chime in as I'm not sure which packages are affected.

@cfr If you want to know the content of a MiKTeX package without using MiKTeX and without installing the MiKTeX console, you can inspect the corresponding *.tar.lzma from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages. They are more or less TDS trees similar to the TeX Live packages. Usually there are also extra source and doc archives.
